# Proper way to two .save() in mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, save

I am trying to save to two different docs and two different models in the same function, but no matter what I try I seem to get weird errors. It seems like for whatever reason mongoose has made this exclusively not work.

I have two findOne functions nested one is finding the book while the other is finding the prof and the object is to update them both to relate to each other.

Is there a recommended way I should do this perhaps two seperate backend endpoints and two seperate functions? that would be one solution to this problem, but I'd like to know why I cannot do whats below.

```
await prof.save().then(async () => {
      await book
            .save()
            .then(() => {
                return res.status(200).json({
                   success: true,
                   message: 'items updated'
             }).catch( (err) => {
                 return res.status(400)
             })
      })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you can not using `await` and `.then .catch` together. if you want update two or more collection in mongoose it's better use [transactions](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html), it's like `rollback` in relational database, but if you are newbie in mongoose it's hard to implement transaction,
without transaction you can do like this

```
try {
 await prof.save();
 await book.save();
 return res.status(200).json({
   success: true,
   message: "items updated",
});
} catch (error) {
   return res.status(400)
}
```

Comment: Hey! I'm having the same problem. I did the same thing as you wrote above but my concern is that isn't it possible that the first promise succeeds and collection gets updated but the other one gets any kind of error and doesn't update.

Comment: You should use transaction, search in google: transaction in mongo @YashSharma

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look at [Mongoose's documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) on middleware, especially the part about pre .save() middleware.
What you want to do is to trigger some function each time an item is saved. Particularly, you want this function to be another save function itself. This needs to be done in your Profs Schema, and you need to require your Books model to make it work:

```
ProfsSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const prof = this;
  try {
    await Books.findOneAndUpdate({ ... });
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
})
```

Of course, this is a very schematic suggestion: the `{ ... }` represents whatever updates you want to apply to your book document. Also, you may want to do different things whether a new prof document is being created with a `if (prof.isNew)` or only trigger these functions when certain fields have been modified `if (prof.field.isModified)`.
In any case, I strongly suggest you learn to use Mongoose's middleware for this kind of purpose: it's a rather powerful tool to interconnect different models across a MongoDB cluster.